# UserControl Dependency Property design time

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, dependency-properties

I'm creating a simple User Control in WPF that contains a TextBlock inside a Button.

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfExpansion.MyButton"..... >
    <Grid >
        <Button Background="Transparent" >
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Text}"/>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And also the "Text" dependency property.

```
public partial class MyButton : UserControl
{
    public MyButton()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;         
    }

    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(MyButton), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

}
```

And then I use the UserControl like this:

```
<MyButton Text="Test" />
```

The problem is that the Visual Studio design does not change, but it works in runtime.

What is wrong?

I also tried

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

Inside the UC definition, without success.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using `FrameworkPropertyMetadata` instead of `PropertyMetadata`, specifying `AffectsRender` like below, then **restart** Visual Studio:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(MyButton),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty,
            FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));
```

[MSDN Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkpropertymetadataoptions?view=netframework-4.7) about `FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender` says

> Some aspect of rendering or layout composition (other than measure or
>   arrange) is affected by value changes to this dependency property.

For other cases, there are options like AffectsMeasure, AffectsArrange, etc.

Comment: Great! At first moment, this doesn't seems to work, so I close and open Visual Studio and it's now working fine. Many Thanks.

Comment: Also had to restart VS2017. Good tip!

Answer (score 1):

Golden shovel candidate, still I came across the same problem and had it solved being inspired by https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1096567/How-to-set-a-custom-dependency-property-of-user-co

Long story short: your dependency property is set on the `UserControl` itself and you are trying to bind the it's child property to it. The child's binding needs to have `RelativeSource` defined, hence the `TextBlock` should look like this:

```
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=Text}" />
```

The only `DataContext` assignment needed is the one you already have in the code behind in the constructor.

---

## UPDATE

But then I tried your attempts and came to the conclusion that if you define the `DataContext` in XAML already, you don't need to provide it in each of the controls. This means you need to define your UC the following way (`d:DataContext=...` does the trick):

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfExpansion.MyButton"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YRS100_Data_Analysis"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <Grid>
        <Button Background="Transparent">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Text}" />
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Works like a charm.