# WPF Design-time property

Tags: c#, wpf

I have built a UserControl that is basically a grid that can have either rounded corners on each end, or a certain polygon. I have a Rounded property that changes the Visibility of the rounded border and the polygon to match (if someone sets Rounded="True", then the rounded border is visible and the polygon is hidden, and vice-versa.

Just like in this question:
[UserControl Dependency Property design time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18158500/usercontrol-dependency-property-design-time)

...it works great at run-time, but I can't seem to get it to reflect the changes at design-time. However, restarting VS, cleaning the solution, rebuilding, changing the build target, etc - none of those steps seem to make a difference. 
My class is pretty basic:

```
public partial class MyBox : UserControl
{
    public MyBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public bool Rounded
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(RoundedProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(RoundedProperty, value);
            this.edgeRounded.Visibility = (value ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Hidden);
            this.edgePolygon.Visibility = (value ? Visibility.Hidden : Visibility.Visible);
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty RoundedProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Rounded", typeof(bool), typeof(MyBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I got this to work by adding a changed event handler and then changing the dependency property registration to reference it:
public static readonly DependencyProperty RoundedProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Rounded", typeof(bool), typeof(MyBox), new PropertyMetadata(false, RoundedChanged));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this to work by adding a changed event handler and then changing the dependency property registration to reference it. My working code:

```
public partial class MyBox : UserControl
{
    public MyBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public bool Rounded
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(RoundedProperty); }
        set { SetValue(RoundedProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty RoundedProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Rounded", typeof(bool), typeof(MyBox), new PropertyMetadata(false, RoundedChanged));

    private static void RoundedChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        bool value = (bool)e.NewValue;
        MyBox thisMyBox = (MyBox)sender;

        // Hide/show the edges
        thisMyBox.edgeRounded.Visibility = (value ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Hidden);
        thisMyBox.edgePolygon.Visibility = (value ? Visibility.Hidden : Visibility.Visible);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use the XAML to bind the visibility property to a datacontext viewmodel.
I have done this with all kinds of things.

Comment: The goal is to have design-time properties, though, so I can have: <local:MyBox Rounded="True" /> and see the edges change based on the design property.

Comment: The model above could inherit from the INotifyPropertyChanged as well  as the UserControl so that you just implement the propertychanged event rather than having the dependencyproperty.